# Only Number with space validation in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Trying number validation with space in it. but its not working for me.

```
if(!user_phone.match(/[^0-9\s]/))
    {
        $('#user_phone').css({"border":"1px solid red"});
        return false;
    }
```

What will be the regex expression i have to use?

Comment: Where do you want Space at?

Comment: "not working" isn't helpful. Does it match more than you want? Less than you want? Which cases it is failing? Does it shut down your computer? Does it produce a cow when run? What is it doing that you don't want it to do, or what is it not doing that you do want it to do? What values have you tested it with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this regex `/^[0-9 ]+$/` or `[0-9 ]+`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which match everything except number and whitespace, you need to put the anchor `^` out of character class:

```
/^[0-9\s]/
```

Also note that if you want to match more than one character you can use modifier `+` to match one or more combinations of number and whitespace :

```
/^[0-9\s]+/
```

And note that `\s` will match all the whitespaces contain tab and ..., if you want to just match the space you need to use space `^[0-9 ]+`.And if you want to use this regex in a multi-line text you need to use flag `m` which makes the regex engine match the anchor `^` from start of each line.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this:

```
/^[\d\s]+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to be done:[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omeu19dn/4/)

Here is the actual code:

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
    user_phone = $('#user_phone').val();
    $('#user_phone').css({"border":"1px solid #ccc"});
    if(!user_phone.match(/^\d[\d\s]+\d$/))
    {
        $('#user_phone').css({"border":"1px solid red"});
    }      
})
```

The check means:

1. if the match is not true, colour the input's border red.
2. In the match is says: if the value is starting with digit and ending with digit (because starting/ending with space doesn't make any sense) and in between there are only numbers and spaces (more than one) than one, then it's a true (but because of the not (!), then it will check for invalid phone numbers.

Also never forget to reset the state, because on later stage you will always get red background if you enter even 1 wrong phone number